# Make checkstyle require variable prefix

Tags: regex, eclipse, checkstyle

I would like all checkbox variables to begin with "ckx".

```
^.*JCheckBox((?! ckx).)*$
```

This works for variable declarations but matches definitions too.
E.g.

```
ckxSomeCheckbox = new JCheckBox();
```

Any idea how to prevent this code to be displayed as an error?

Valid examples:

```
private JCheckBox ckxTest = new JCheckBox();
public javax.swing.JCheckBox ckxTest;
```

Invalid examples:

```
private JCheckBox abcTest;
private JCheckBox abcckxTest;
ckxTest = new JCheckBox();
ckxTest = new JCheckBox("");
```

Comment: The original regex disallows a space followed with `ckx` anywhere after `JCheckBox`. If you want to prevent it at the beginning you probably need `^.*JCheckBox\s*\((?!\s*ckx).*$`. And to prevent matching `()`, add it as a lookahead: [`^.*JCheckBox\s*\((?!\))(?!\s*ckx).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/1LWN45/1). Double escape ``\`` chars if you are using it inside a string literal.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work yet. I provided some examples.

Comment: Oh sorry.. it's ckx

Comment: Maybe you want to require the var to start wit `ckx`  after`JCheckBox`? See [`^.*JCheckBox\s+ckx.*$`](https://regex101.com/r/1LWN45/3).

Comment: Which Checkstyle check are you trying to configure?

Comment: I am trying to configure the RegexpSingleLineJava check. I know that the lines don't compile. Those are just examples of lines that should/shouldn't be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the [RegexpMultiline](https://checkstyle.org/config_regexp.html#RegexpMultiline) check so that you catch cases where people insert line breaks into the code in inconvenient places.

The regex would be `\bJCheckBox\b\s*(?!ckx[A-Z])\w+` ([explanation / examples](https://regex101.com/r/NLG8kw/2)).

```xml
<module name="RegexpMultiline">
  <property name="format" value="\bJCheckBox\b\s*(?!ckx[A-Z])\w+"/>
  <property name="message" value="Missing prefix 'ckx' on checkbox variable"/>
  <property name="fileExtensions" value="java"/>
</module>
```

Note that I took out the lines where the faulty identifier is at the start of the line, because those lines would not compile. Unless you have the variable declared earlier, in which case that would be where the issue was flagged.

```java
ckxTest = new JCheckBox(); 
ckxTest = new JCheckBox("");
```

Checking this with a regex isn't perfect, because people can use comments or subclasses to confuse the detector. So it would be a more powerful approach to use a [PMD XPath rule](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.5.0/pmd_userdocs_extending_writing_xpath_rules.html) or something, but that's for another question. :-)

---

The same could be achieved using [RegexpSinglelineJava](https://checkstyle.org/config_regexp.html#RegexpSinglelineJava), which adds the ability to ignore comments, but would be derailed by unexpected line breaks:

```xml
<module name="RegexpSinglelineJava">
  <property name="format" value="\bJCheckBox\b\s*(?!ckx[A-Z])\w+"/>
  <property name="message" value="Missing prefix 'ckx' on checkbox variable"/>
  <property name="ignoreComments" value="true"/>
</module>
```

Comment: Could you add a solution with RegexpSingleLineJava? The formatter won't allow line breaks for variable declarations :)

Comment: Ok, added a section on *RegexpSinglelineJava*.